# JavaScript function with 'undefined' parameter

Tags: javascript, modernizr

Going around Modernizr source code I have found strange thing:

```
window.Modernizr = (function(window,document,undefined) {
```

After that this function will be called with two arguments (`this, this.document`).

Why `undefined` is used here? Is it meaningful or it's just strange code-style?

Comment: I know that this construction is overriding undefined in function context, but I can't understand for what.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Creates a local `undefined` in case someone redefines `undefined` somewhere in the scope chain.

Also provides a faster lookup since `undefined` is a global property, so the scope chain traversal is reduced.

Comment: Wow, thanks for fast answer. I don't think about that.

Comment: Yes, I believe Paul Irish refers to that as the asshole effect in the 10 things I learned about JQuery video.