# Why does jQuery's animation extension "jQuery Color" 's closure function take an undefined value as it's second parameter?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript function with ‘undefined’ parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4650442/javascript-function-with-undefined-parameter)

I'm looking the jQuery Color source code here

http://code.jquery.com/color/jquery.color-2.1.0.js

And I found that the closure function take an undefined value as it's second parameter.
See below:

```
(function( jQuery, undefined ) {

    var stepHooks = "backgroundColor borderBottomColor borderLeftColor borderRightColor borderTopColor color columnRuleColor outlineColor textDecorationColor textEmphasisColor",

    // plusequals test for += 100 -= 100
    rplusequals = /^([\-+])=\s*(\d+\.?\d*)/,
    // a set of RE's that can match strings and generate color tuples.
```

Or you can see it in the source code. Look at the second parameter.

The point I want to know is that why the second parameter is undefined?

I think it is an approach to strictly set the function to receive only one parameter.

I'm I right? Or anyone can help me out?

Answer (score 5):

That's in case some other part of the code assigns some value to the `undefined` name. The closure is actually called with only one argument, as:

```
(function(jQuery, undefined) {
    // ...
})(jQuery);
```

That ensures that `undefined` is actually bound to `undefined` within the closure.

Comment: Because, for some unfathomable reason, `undefined` is not a keyword.

Comment: still dont get it.. so is it just related to naming convention? any example??

Comment: @Amitd, let's consider that a (possibly malicious) script in the page assigns `"foo"` to `undefined`. Without this workaround, comparisons to `undefined` would not work properly (they would become comparisons to `"foo"`) and the resulting behavior would be quite hard to understand and diagnose.

Comment: That is, "undefined" is't a keyword and can assign a value to it? Let me try it...

Comment: I've tried, but I can't assign a value to undefined. It came back to itself after the assignment. In Chrome

Comment: @Xieranmaya, you must be using a recent browser that conforms to version 5 of the ECMA specs. Not all browsers do that.