# What is the point of undefined as function argument?

Tags: javascript

I keep seeing in OSS source code functions that have `undefined` as parameter, e.g. like this from fancybox:

```
(function (window, document, $, undefined) {
    "use strict";
    // snip-snip
}(window, document, jQuery));
```

Or [this from jquery validate](https://github.com/DiegoLopesLima/Validate/blob/master/jquery-validate.js#L2):

```
;(function(defaults, $, undefined) {
   // snip, snip
})({
   // snip, snip settings
}, jQuery);
```

Is there some reason why?

---

EDIT: Okay, so I get it that it gets defined undefined locally but I have an issue with this, checking something is `undefined` won't work sometimes:

```
if (thing === undefined) {} 
    // will crash if thing has never been initialized

if (typeof thing === 'undefined') {} 
    // always works
```

Is there some performance gain to this or something?

Comment: To avoid unexpected results when someone uses `var undefined=<some non-undefined value>;` at the global level.

Comment: Question already asked :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4650442/javascript-function-with-undefined-parameter

Comment: I tried to google it... failed. Which is why I asked this question in particular.

Comment: so I edited the question a bit

Comment: It's typically used to compare `obj.x` against `undefined` whereby `obj` is not null.